# Escape the <b> tag on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a form with textfield by using content editable div. Idea is to add bold tag when I press button bold and on second click on that button, it should leave the bold tag and text should be normal.

Here is my code,

```js
      $('.btn-bold').click(function(){
            $('.btn-bold').css({'background-color':'white'});
            $('.container-main').append('<b>Text</b>');
      });
```

```css
.container{
            width: 400px;
            height: 200px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-top: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #00000010;
            border-radius: 5px;
      }
      
      .container-top{
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
      }
      
      .container-main{
            float: left;
            width: 96%;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: aliceblue;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 15px;
            outline: none;
            padding: 10px 2% 10px 2%;
      }
      
      .btn{
            float: left;
            width: auto;
            height: 40px;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            margin: 2px;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: antiquewhite;
            font-size: 20px;
      }
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title> Demo
    </title>
</head>

<div class="container">
      <div class="container-top">
            <button class="btn btn-bold material-icons"> format_bold </button>
      </div>
      
      <div class="container-main" contenteditable="true"></div>
</div>
```

What things I should change in the script to achieve this correctly?

Note - If this question is available in stack overflow before, please let me know. I have added this because I could not find the correct answer.

Comment: so you want to remove the <b> tag and its content when the element is clicked 2nd time?

Comment: @sid Exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

I changed it so the white is a css class that is toggled and depending on if the class is enabled or not change what is added to the div

```js
$('.btn-bold').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('white');
  if($(this).hasClass('white')){
    $('.container-main').append('<b>Test</b>');
  }else{
    $('.container-main').append('Test');
  }
});
```

```css
.container{
            width: 400px;
            height: 200px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-top: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #00000010;
            border-radius: 5px;
      }
      
      .container-top{
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
      }
      
      .container-main{
            float: left;
            width: 96%;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: aliceblue;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 15px;
            outline: none;
            padding: 10px 2% 10px 2%;
      }
      
      .btn{
            float: left;
            width: auto;
            height: 40px;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            margin: 2px;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: antiquewhite;
            font-size: 20px;
      }
      .white {
        background-color: white;
      }
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title> Demo
    </title>
</head>

<div class="container">
      <div class="container-top">
            <button class="btn btn-bold material-icons"> format_bold </button>
      </div>
      
      <div class="container-main" contenteditable="true"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer. Just one problem. Whenever I clear the word 'Test' it goes inside the b tag again, and the font becomes bold. So I have added <p>Test</p>, which is working as intended, but it creates the new line.

Comment: @BidhanMajhi try `<span>` instead of `<p>`

Comment: Added &nbsp; to add a space which kinda solved the problem.However, I am keeping the question open to get different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

```js
      $('.btn-bold').click(function () {
        $('.btn-bold').css({'background-color': 'white'});
        if (!$('.container-main').hasClass('bold')) {
            $('.container-main').addClass('bold');
        } else {
            $('.container-main').removeClass('bold');
        }
    });
```

```css
.bold {
           font-weight: bold;
 }
.container{
            width: 400px;
            height: 200px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-top: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #00000010;
            border-radius: 5px;
      }
      
      .container-top{
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
      }
      
      .container-main{
            float: left;
            width: 96%;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: aliceblue;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 15px;
            outline: none;
            padding: 10px 2% 10px 2%;
      }
      
      .btn{
            float: left;
            width: auto;
            height: 40px;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            margin: 2px;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: antiquewhite;
            font-size: 20px;
      }
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title> Demo
    </title>
</head>

<div class="container">
      <div class="container-top">
            <button class="btn btn-bold material-icons"> format_bold </button>
      </div>
      
      <div class="container-main" contenteditable="true"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't what he asked for. He wanted to be able to continue typing normal text while there still being bold text in the div. This makes all text either bold or not bold.